# How can I reduce the space of before text in jquery mobile button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using J query Mobile and ASP.net in my project. In That buttons are stench with the web browser.

So See the First Image That I mark read Arrow. That Space fixed, so my button text are going to invisible.

If you are using jquery mobile. please tell where can I reduce the space of before text.

Is understandable?

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My Code**

I am using jquery mobile Grid,. But i am not using links, I am using buttons.

and my css jquery.mobile-1.0b3.css and scripts are,..

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<div class="ui-grid-b">                
                <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>             
                <div class="ui-block-c"> <asp:Button ID="btnUp" runat="server" Text="UP" onclick="btnUp_Click" /></div>    
                <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"> <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"> <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>                       
                <div class="ui-block-c"><asp:Button ID="btnDown" runat="server" Text="DOWN" onclick="btnDown_Click" /></div>               
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->
```

Comment: Are you using the jQuery Mobile grids? In any case can you post the code or create a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Jasper I am not know JSFiddle. Please see my updated question.

Comment: JSFiddle is [jsfiddle.net](jsfiddle.net). And it would be better if you posted the generated HTML and not the server-side code. Have you simply tried to reduce the padding?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS:

```
<style>
    .ui-grid-b .ui-btn { margin: 0; }
</style>
```

Adjust the margins as needed.